# If possible to callback in Google passes, while open a wallet?

Tags: php, google-wallet

I have successfully created an Google pass using PHP.
The pass is added in the Google wallet successfully, and the pass auto update working fine

Now, is there an option to update the pass, when I open the Google wallet. If Yes, please help me with the steps to follow.

please help me on this to solve about the  problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: [ask] includes reporting your prior research. Do the docs say anything?

Comment: There is no callback for when the pass is opened, only when it is created and deleted